# Aligned Stacked Bar Chart

Tags: python, data-visualization

Is there a type of stacked bar chart where there are gaps in the bars in order to align each category? Alternatively is there a type of heatmap where the grid changes proportionally to the category size?

Something that looks like this:
[image]

Code to reproduce example:

```py
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

# Create subset data
subset_sizes = {
    '1000': 0.0937, '0100': 0.0083, '1100': 0.0677, '0010': 0.0014, '1010': 0.0781, 
    '0110': 0.1087, '1110': 0.1667, '0001': 0.0005, '1001': 0.0875, '0101': 0.0032, 
    '1101': 0.0734, '0011': 0.002, '1011': 0.0731, '0111': 0.0519, '1111': 0.1824
}

# Turn subsets into dataframe of entries
stacked_bar_data = []
for subset, value in subset_coverages.items():
    for wine_i, d in enumerate(subset):
        if d == '1':
            stacked_bar_data.append((str(wine_i), subset, value))
        else:
            stacked_bar_data.append((str(wine_i), subset+'NA', value))   
stacked_bar_df = pd.DataFrame(stacked_bar_data, columns=['group', 'category', 'value'])

# Sort each group for each category so that each group appears in the same order
stacked_bar_df = stacked_bar_df.sort_values(['category', 'group'], ascending=False)

# Stacked bar chart
fig = px.bar(stacked_bar_df, x="group", y="value", color="category", title="Aligned Stacked Bar Chart")
fig.update_layout(barmode='stack', bargap=0)

# Hide category+group pairs that aren't present
for i in range(len(fig.data)):
    if fig.data[i]['name'][-2:] == 'NA':
        fig.data[i]['showlegend'] = False
        fig.data[i]['marker']['color'] = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0)'

fig.show()
```

Comment: Would a treemap of some sort express the desired visualization?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @BeRT2me Treemaps could do the trick. The one thing i don't like about them is the sub-categories aren't aligned, so with more categories it gets harder to see which groups overlap.

Comment: `subset_coverages.items()` should be `subset_sizes.items()` no?

Comment: Same thing. In my case I was looking at how much of 0-1 is covered. Hence the name coverages.